# ~ta ra / ~たら volitional

Tags: translation

I'd like to say

> When I'll pass the test, I will be glad/happy.

I came up with

> テストが合格したから、嬉しです。

Is it correct?

Comment: What part are you least sure about? (Giving the details would help make this question more specific and less a general proofreading question.)

Answer (score 1):

嬉しい, you need an extra い at the end there :P

You're asking about たら ending, but not using it anywhere. You have 合格したから where the から would mean "because". The actual verb conjugation you have here is 合格した, and the から isn't needed for what you want. Can you see how you can change 合格した to use a ～たら ending instead?

Comment: You are absolutely right!  I wanted to ask about  から. So If I want to say that When I pass the test I will be glad, I have drop から?

Comment: Yes, in this context it's like だから, so you could say for example 試験に合格したから... to mean "because I passed the exam...".

Comment: very helpful! ありがとうございます！